# ~/.bashrc not autosourced in 12.04 lts

Tags: 12.04, bashrc

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820517/bashrc-at-ssh-login#comment19133537_820533) says, the `~/.bashrc` is sourced automatically in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server, which  I use. 
I don't know where he got this information from, but as it is not downvoted yet, I believe it is true.

I used this script to check if it is sourced:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   echo "Not sourced!";
fi
```

Just for info: Permissions at the moment are 775 and owner is me.

So why is my `~/.bashrc` not sourced?

Comment: that script is not going to tell you if a script is sourced, it is going to tell you if that file exists and is regular.

Comment: Ok thank you @Jay_silly_evarlast_Wren 
How do I check if it is sourced then?

Comment: Do you have a .profile file in your home dir? `ll ~/.profile` That file calls the .bashrc (because it is autosourced, not the .bashrc):

`if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi`

Comment: Well, an easy test to determine whatever your ~/.bashrc is being sourced or not would be to set an alias or an environment variable in it.

Comment: @B.Roland The ~/.profile is not existing for my homedir. Is the sourcing of the bashrc only made via this file?

Comment: Yes, it is made with the .profile. I answer you right now.

Comment: Thank you @B.Roland. You completely answered my question now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As we found out, you have no `.profile` file in your home. Look at the bash's manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) for Bash startup files.

Make a .profile for yourself:

`nano ~/.profile`

Insert this text to that file (copied from Debian Squeeze):

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

*Tip: if you are making a new user, use the `-m` switch to make him a dir, and place the default files, eg.: `sudo useradd example -m -d /home/example`*

Comment: Out of curiosity: What permissions do we need for .bashrc and .profile? And who got to be the owner and ownergroup? Thanks for posting the answer.

Comment: It is your own, so copy your homedir's permissions. Mine are different from the homedir's (755), the .bashrc's: 644... but it doesn't really matter, just need to be readable by you.

Comment: Otherwise you may have a .bash_logout file also: http://paste2.org/p/2970860 (you may tumb up my answer, it is used to do that's how here)

Comment: I would if I could!

Answer (score 0):

You can see exactly what is executed by using bash verbose mode.

For a non-login shell:

```
$ bash -v 2>&1 | less
```

For a login shell:

```
$ bash -vl 2>&1 | less
```

I don't have a 12.04 system on hand to confirm that .bashrc is executed when using login shell. I'm fairly certain that it is. If it is not, I would guess that you, or whatever is invoking bash on your behalf, are not specifying a login shell. Examples of this is remote command execution via ssh.

ssh to get a shell spawns a login shell

```
$ ssh remotehost
```

ssh to invoke a remote command does not spawn a login shell

```
$ ssh remotehost remotecommand
```

Also see the bash man page --norc option which mentions that this option is on by default if bash is invoked as sh. This used to be important, but less so now that ubuntu has moved to dash for sh instead of bash.